# Push Registry unregister Connection

Tags: exception, java-me

I'm working with J2ME application, that works to send/receive sms from specific port. Somehow I made some mistake with the code and make the application goes error. When I already solve the error the application always receive 2 sms (the first one that error and the second one is already solved). Because of that my application cannot be working properly, and when I try to change the port it works again (the receive sms module).

When I try to test it to receive via method `notifyIncomingMessage(MessageConnection mc)` from class `MessageListener` using different port 31211 (the first port is 31210), the midlet didn't start. Because the midlet is already been registered on the first port (`PushRegistry.registerConnection("sms://:31210", "my_midlet_class_name", "*")`).

I try to unregister the connection using `PushRegistry.unregisterConnection("sms://:31210")` but somehow an exception occur `Security java/lang/SecurityException Registered by another MIDlet suite`. After that I change the midlet class name and it works.

The question is: **How to unregister the connection from url `sms://:31210` since the url I already change to `sms://:31211` without changing the midlet class name?**

*Note:*

- I'm using Nokia C3-00 for the device
- S40 as the OS
- CLDC 1.1 & MIDP 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Only the `MIDlet` that registered the first port can unregister it. If you can, install an update for the first `MIDlet` (bigger version number) without a call to `registerConnection` and calling `unregisterConnection`.

**Update**

According to [this article](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_launch_a_MIDlet_remotely_via_SMS_or_locally_via_an_Alarm_with_PushRegistry_in_Java_ME) from Nokia:

> **Warning**: Static and dynamic registration cannot co-exist for the same
>   Connection URL. Static registration reserves the port the moment the
>   application is installed and from that point on, dynamic registration
>   on the same port will fail.

Comment: Yes, already try that, and the Security Exception shows up. Do you know where the connection is saved? Is it in the file same as the `RecordStore` concept? I want to delete it manually if the file exists.

Comment: Is the MIDlet signed? If so, the update must be signed with the same keys.

Comment: Everything (but the version) from original MIDlet suite must be preserved: name, vendor, etc. Did you change any other thing?

Comment: Nope, I just change the MIDlet class name and the port (So that, I can running it again without unregister the connection). And what I want now is to unregister the connection of the old class name of the MIDlet with the previous port.

Comment: If you change the MIDlet class name you can not unregister the old port.

Comment: Yes, I know, before that I tried to restore it to the default. Change to the old class name again, change to the old port. And try to unregister `PusRegistry.unregisterConnection("sms://:31210")` and the exception occur. That's my problem now...

Comment: Can you uninstall the original MIDlet? And any other that might have registered that sms port?